# Не корректно отображается адаптация сайта на мобильных устройствах

Tags: css, css3, mobile, responsive, mobile-web

При адаптации сайта, проверяю через браузер выбирая подходящие устройства. Сайт отображается как надо, но на самих устройствах, он отображается не корректно. Некоторые элементы “плывут”, на Айфоне, некоторые элементы вообще не отображаются. В чем может быть замин. И почему в браузере все нормально, а на мобильных устройствах немного не так?
Как быть? Что делать? Буду благодарен любому совету.

Вот так отображается на 5"[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А так на 5.2" [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Для Apple это вообще не отображаеться. 
Я Круглый новичек в верстке, простите уж. Надеюсь на понимание.

```
 <div id="footer">
        <div id="contacts">
            <div class="inf">
                <div class="text-contacts">098 118 57 48<br>095 575 64 82<br>info@bsdasdaassdak.com
                </div>
                <div class="icons">
                    <a href="#"><img src="img/instagram.png"></a>
                    <a href="#"><img src="img/telegram.png"></a>
                    <a href="#"><img src="img/viber.png"></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="menu">
            <nav>
                <ul class="bot-nav">
                    <li class="dws-li"><a href="javascript://0" onclick="slowScroll ('#home')">Главная</a></li>
                    <li class="dws-li"><a href="javascript://0" onclick="slowScroll ('#about')">О нас</a></li>
                    <li class="dws-li"><a href="javascript://0" onclick="slowScroll ('#offers')">Наши услуги</a></li>
                    <li class="dws-li"><a href="javascript://0" onclick="slowScroll ('#forma')">Клиентам</a></li>
                    <li class="dws-li"><a href="javascript://0" onclick="slowScroll ('#footer')">Контакты</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </div>
```

НЕ АДАПТИРОВАННЫЙ КОД:

```
 #footer{
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#e9e9e9), to(#FFFFFF));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #e9e9e9, #FFFFFF);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #e9e9e9, #FFFFFF);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #e9e9e9, #FFFFFF);
    height: 100vh;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
}
.inf{
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    height: 850px;
    width: 850px;
    background-image: url(../img/contacts.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    right: 80px;
    bottom: 150px;
}
.inf a img{
    margin: 0 4px 0 4px;
    height: 40px;
    width: auto;
}
.icons{
    position: absolute;
    margin: 470px auto auto 342px;
}
.text-contacts{
    font-family: Cuprum;
    font-size: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 340px auto auto 338px;
}
```

АДАПТИРОВАННЫЙ КОД:

```
@media screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-width: 480px)and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2){
#contacts{
    width: 100%;
}
#footer{
    height: 88vh;
}
.inf{
    width: 110% ;
    height: 80%; 
    left:-35%;
    margin-top: 80%;
}
.inf a img{
    margin: 0 2px 0 2px;
    height: auto;
    width: 10%;
}
.icons{
    margin: 54% auto auto 39%;
}
.text-contacts{
    font-size: 13px;
    margin: 38% auto auto 36%;
}
```

}

Comment: https://itchief.ru/lessons/html-and-css/css-browser-prefixes

Comment: @AlexandrMaliovaniy префиксы прописаны уже, спасибо.

Comment: а медиа-запросы?(@media)

Comment: @Евгений Конечно, без медиа даже в браузере не корректно отображаться будет.

Comment: вначале надо бы сделать так чтоб без медиа корректно отображался сайт, а потом уже адаптировать под устройство с помощью media... ширину менять и т.д., чтоб не плыли.

Comment: viewport  meta tag прописан?

Comment: @slowBro <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"> ПРАВИЛЬНО?

Comment: @ЮрийГалай может код хотя бы предоставите или скрины проблемы?

Comment: @Vadizar Добавил

Comment: @ЮрийГалай а как должно на БЫТЬ?

Comment: @Vadizar Логично, что должно отображаться как на 5.2"